# Is there an ExpressJS middleware for RequireJS optimizer?

Tags: node.js, express, requirejs, amd

I don't want to use any build process to run RequireJS optimizer.
Is there an ExpressJS middleware for RequireJS optimizer?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this [example](https://gist.github.com/mdellanoce/1453578) for optimizing. It configures app to optimize js files, and then use it. This should work as good as middleware.

Comment: RequreJS does the optimization statically. The example then links the files, so yes you would have to do that. Did you want it to happen on the fly because optimisation takes time, and should not be done on request basis.

Comment: I hoped it can happen on express load time (like in the example), but keep a translation table from the original paths.